VS2022 resource "The neutral resource is of the type system.string"
What does The neutral resource is of the type system.string inconsistent mean?

VS2022 new Resource file. There isn't a way for me to change the type of resource.
And it only happens to a few entries, not all.
The resource files are giving lots of problem since a VS2022 update about 2 months ago.
